# Closed question can be poked by the community

Tags: support, community-user

I was browsing the GameDev StackExchange site, and one of the questions came up to the newest category, because the Community user updated it.

This would be fine, if that specific question wasn't closed since april 2013 already,

[Good GUI for OpenGL?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/3617/good-gui-for-opengl)

Why is this possible? If the asker never found a good answer, then finding one when there are no new answers is prettty much impossible.

Answer (score 5):

An anonymous user [suggested an edit](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/63626), which was approved.

This is what bumped the post.

Comment: Then why are anonymous edits marked as they were edited by community?

Comment: @Bálint Who else are they going to be attributed to? They're anonymous. I suppose there could be a "Anonymous" "user" but seems like "Community" is what we already have.